# obj-c: iPhone programming: change selection on pickerview programmatically

Tags: uipickerview

I got a pickerview and I want to add a code that will automatically show at the user the row I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`-selectRow:…` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006842-CH3-SW8).

```
[thePickerView selectRow:123 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```